# Javascript HTML Scraping

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

I am working with a web page with just  plain text - how can I go about 'scraping' the data and then storing it into an array variable. There are no tags (i.e. no 'div','id' etc.)

The html looks like something like this (i.e. if you were to view the source code it would just be completely plain text w/o markup)

HTML (view-source:www.blablabla.com/path.txt):

```
Hello World My Name is John
```

I would like to store each word into an array along the lines of:

var array = ["Hello", "World", "My", "Name", "is", "John"];

Comment: Without code we cannot give you solid advice. Please post your HTML code in the question and the format you like to achieve.

Comment: Scraping it into an array might involve use of split() or regular expressions, so it depends on the format of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using node's `http` , you can just read the data directly.

```
var http = require('http');

http.get('http://www.example.com', function(res) {

}).on('data', function(chunk) {
  // do something with the chunk here, for example print it out
  console.log('body: ' + chunk);
});
```

An easier way to do this would be via the `request` package

```
var request = require('request');

request('http://www.example.com', function(err, resp, body) {
  if(!error && resp.statusCode == 200) {
    // do something with body
    var array = body.split(/(\s+)/);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry - can you explain that a little more?

Comment: One question I have is will the split method work if the data its scraping is numbers instead of a string? For example if the data for body.split() is numbers, will split create an array of numbers or an array of strings (with each number being a string i.e. '7' instead of 7)? I am looking through the documentation of split method and didn't know what the analogue for numbers was